# Eloquent relationships question between 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have these 4 tables:

```
events (id, name, date)
drivers (id, first_name, last_name)
participants (id, number, event_id, driver_id, codriver_id)
penalties (id, event_id, participant_id)
```

How I can get the driver/codriver first_name and last_name when show the penalties table?

I tried with this, but not works:

```
$grid->participant()->driver()->full_name();
$grid->participant()->codriver()->full_name();
```

Penalty model:

```
public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
    }
```

Participant model:

```
public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class);
    }

    public function codriver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class);
    }
```

Driver model:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
```

How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`->relation_name()` returns relation query builder:

To get relation object/objects you should call relation as property, not as function (same with full_name attribute):

```
$grid->participant->driver->full_name;
```

It is equel to:

```
$grid->participant()->first()->driver()->first()->full_name;
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I need to call as function. For example ``$grid->participant()->number() ``works fine, but ``$grid->participant()->driver()->full_name();`` no.